# Executing python function from HTML button click in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a program that needs has an HTML button. I need it to execute a python function when it is clicked. The function doesn't change anything on the webpage other than rerouting to another page. How do I do this?

HTML Button

```html
    <div>
    <button class="submit-btn success"><a href="/end">Press after submission</a></button>
    </div>
```

Python Function

```
def PyFunc():
   df = pd.DataFrame(data)
   print(df)
```

Comment: from where do you get the `data` ? and paste your flask code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [call python function from html code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27001063/call-python-function-from-html-code)

Comment: know that doesn't answer my question. Sorry.